# "Error mounting (drive name/dir name): wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock" 22.04.2 LTS

Tags: command-line, partitioning, mount, hard-drive, windows

I am suddenly unable to mount either of my NFTS drives. This is an example of the message from one of them.

The error message from the files GUI:

[image: Screenshot]

Both drives were plugged into another computer and appear to be working fine.

I ran `sudo dmesg` from another post on this site with this issue. The output where there are several errors:

```
el_lockdown.7
[   82.485364] rfkill: input handler disabled
[  103.999759] rfkill: input handler enabled
[  104.836575] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[  104.836581] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[  104.836587] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[  108.116237] Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
[  112.115147] rfkill: input handler disabled
[  113.103393] ntfs3: Max link count 4000
[  113.103396] ntfs3: Enabled Linux POSIX ACLs support
[  113.103397] ntfs3: Read-only LZX/Xpress compression included
**[  113.103913] ntfs3: Unknown parameter 'windows_names'**
[  113.262856] ntfs: driver 2.1.32 [Flags: R/O MODULE].
**[  113.263346] ntfs: (device sdb3): parse_options(): Unrecognized mount option windows_names.**
**[  145.865905] ntfs3: Unknown parameter 'windows_names'**
**[  145.865954] ntfs: (device sdb3): parse_options(): Unrecognized mount option windows_names.**
**[  194.441562] ntfs3: Unknown parameter 'windows_names'**
**[  194.441607] ntfs: (device sdb3): parse_options(): Unrecognized mount option windows_names.**
[  779.265213] wlp1s0: Limiting TX power to 30 (30 - 0) dBm as advertised by 58:24:29:9b:9f:61
**[10435.438921] ntfs3: Unknown parameter 'windows_names'**
**[10435.438971] ntfs: (device sdb3): parse_options(): Unrecognized mount option windows_names.**
**[10438.059557] ntfs3: Unknown parameter 'windows_names'**
**[10438.059587] ntfs: (device sdb3): parse_options(): Unrecognized mount option windows_names.**
**[10480.286723] ntfs3: Unknown parameter 'windows_names'**
**[10480.286782] ntfs: (device sdb3): parse_options(): Unrecognized mount option windows_names.**
```

Pointed out with the `**` on each side of the line. Seems like `windows names` could be an issue.

nfs-common is installed

Ran `sudo fdisk -l`

Output:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 1.82 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Disk model: ST2000DM001-1ER1
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 37536B23-BABF-411E-A824-359B663AC1C9

Device       Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1     2048    1050623    1048576  512M EFI System
/dev/sda2  1050624 3907028991 3905978368  1.8T Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/sdb: 465.76 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Disk model: 00AZLX-60K2TA0  
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: E8147ADA-19F9-40D2-AFF6-8C0E2892B2CE

Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdb1       2048   1023999   1021952   499M EFI System
/dev/sdb2    1024000   1286143    262144   128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sdb3    1286144 967014399 965728256 460.5G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sdb4  967014400 976773119   9758720   4.7G Windows recovery environment


Disk /dev/zram0: 256 MiB, 268435456 bytes, 65536 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 4096 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
```

`/dev/sdb3` is our target. I then `sudo -i` to root

Then I `sudo mount /dev/sdb /media`

Output:
`mount: /media: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.`

Ran `fsck /dev/sdb3`
Output:
`fsck from util-linux 2.37.2`

Ran `sudo tune2fs -c 1 /dev/sdb3`
Output:
`tune2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdb3 /dev/sdb3 contains a ntfs file system labelled 'ohk'`

"ohk" is the name of the drive. Both drives get the same outputs when testing the other one.

How do I go about fixing this? I have Timeshift snapshots but I'd rather not do that unless I absolutely have to.

Comment: Did you run chkdsk in Windows? NTFS is a proprietary Microsoft Windows filesystem so it's better to use their tools to fix it. You could try `ntfsfix` in Ubuntu but would only suggest that if Windows is not available.

Comment: I did not run chkdsk on Windows. I do have access though. I ran the ntfsfix and the drive was mounted, it looks like it didn't delete anything so that's a relief. My other drive has sensitive things

Comment: So was it just the way Ubuntu was reading my partition that was the issue? The drives worked fine on another computer

Comment: Just coming back to say I ran "sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdb3" on one drive, it did not delete anything, and the other drive having issue mounted just fine without needing the command ran on it too.Everything is well now. Thank you for that tip Nmath!